# Consolidate array based on common property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm writing a small little app powered by VueJS and ExpressionEngine that displays a golf tournament leaderboard. A tournament can require that you play more than one course. The data coming out of the database is shown below (rounds).

The problem is that I need to restructure the rounds array so that it looks like the leaderboard array. I'm having a bit of writers block on how to accomplish this. Any guidance would be overwhelmingly appreciated!

```
rounds: [
   {
      team: "Dropkick Murphies",
      score: 75,
      course: 17
   },
   {
      team: "Dropkick Murphies",
      score: 62,
      course: 24
   },
   {
      team: "Dropkick Murphies",
      score: 69,
      course: 26
   },
   {
      team: "Gigantic",
      score: 67,
      course: 26
   },
   {
      team: "Gigantic",
      score: 65,
      course: 17
   },
   {
      team: "Gigantic",
      score: 63,
      course: 24
   }
]
```

```
leaderboard: [
   {
      team: 'Dropkick Murphys',
      rounds: [
         {
            score: 75,
            course: 17
         },
         {
            score: 62,
            course: 24
         },
         {
            score: 69,
            course: 26
         },
   },
   {
      team: 'Wooden Jellyfishes',
      rounds: [
         {
            score: 68,
            course: 24
         },
         {
            score: 65,
            course: 17
         },
         {
            score: 70,
            course: 26
         }
   },
]
```

Comment: Hey @Luke, it is highly recommended to display an attempted code to what you want to approach. Stackoverflow is not a request and receive site, we assist with written code. Please revise your question above to be less vague.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for this is using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). On each iteration you can check if the current analyzed object already exists on the accumulated array (i.e an object with the same `team name` already exists). Then you can use this condition for push a new entire object into the accumulated array or just add a new set of data to the `rounds` array:

```js
const rounds = [
   {team: "Dropkick Murphies", score: 75, course: 17},
   {team: "Dropkick Murphies", score: 62, course: 24},
   {team: "Dropkick Murphies", score: 69, course: 26},
   {team: "Gigantic", score: 67, course: 26},
   {team: "Gigantic", score: 65, course: 17},
   {team: "Gigantic", score: 63, course: 24}
];

let res = rounds.reduce((r, {team, score, course}) =>
{
   let found = r.findIndex(x => x.team === team);
   
   if (found >= 0)
       r[found].rounds.push({score: score, course: course});
   else
       r.push({team: team, rounds: [{score: score, course: course}]});

   return r;

}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a helper function for the conversion.

```
function convertRoundsToLeaderBoard(rounds) {
    var indexes = {};
    var leaderBoard = [];
    for (var round of rounds) {
        if (indexes[round.team] === undefined) {
            indexes[round.team] = leaderBoard.length;
            leaderBoard.push({
                team: round.team,
                rounds: [{score: round.score, course: round.course}]
            });
        } else {
            leaderBoard[indexes[round.team]].rounds.push({score: round.score, course: round.course});
        }
    }
    return leaderBoard;
}
```

Let's test it:

```
convertRoundsToLeaderBoard(
[
   {
      team: "Dropkick Murphies",
      score: 75,
      course: 17
   },
   {
      team: "Dropkick Murphies",
      score: 62,
      course: 24
   },
   {
      team: "Dropkick Murphies",
      score: 69,
      course: 26
   },
   {
      team: "Gigantic",
      score: 67,
      course: 26
   },
   {
      team: "Gigantic",
      score: 65,
      course: 17
   },
   {
      team: "Gigantic",
      score: 63,
      course: 24
   }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to key your data by team using a `Map`. That way you can build your data with a `forEach` loop with linear time complexity:

```js
const rounds = [{team: "Dropkick Murphies",score: 75,course: 17},{team: "Dropkick Murphies",score: 62,course: 24},{team: "Dropkick Murphies",score: 69,course: 26},{team: "Gigantic",score: 67,course: 26},{team: "Gigantic",score: 65,course: 17},{team: "Gigantic",score: 63,course: 24}];

// Create Map with one entry per team
const map = new Map(rounds.map(({team}) => [team, []]));
// Populate each team with their scores
rounds.forEach(({team,score,course}) => map.get(team).push({score,course}));
// Convert the Map to the desired data structure
const result = Array.from(map, ([team, rounds]) => ({team, rounds}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but here's another:

```
var data = {
    rounds: [{
            team: "Dropkick Murphies",
            score: 75,
            course: 17
        },
        ...
    ]
};

var groups = {};
for (var o of data.rounds) {
    if (!groups[o.team])
        groups[o.team] = [];
    groups[o.team].push({
        score: o.score,
        course: o.course
    });
}
var result = [];
for (var g in groups) {
    result.push({
        team: g,
        rounds: groups[g]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using reduce.

here we are using **`team name`** as key property and checking if it is already in output object we push the **`score`** and **`course`** in rounds property of that particular team key if not than we create a new key.

```js
const rounds = [
   {team: "Dropkick Murphies", score: 75, course: 17},
   {team: "Dropkick Murphies", score: 62, course: 24},
   {team: "Dropkick Murphies", score: 69, course: 26},
   {team: "Gigantic", score: 67, course: 26},
   {team: "Gigantic", score: 65, course: 17},
   {team: "Gigantic", score: 63, course: 24}
];

let op = rounds.reduce((output,current)=>{
  if(output[current.team]){
    output[current.team].rounds.push({
      score : current.score,
      course: current.score
    })} else {
      output[current.team] = {
        team: current.team,
        rounds: [{score:current.score, course:current.course}]
      }
    }
 return output 
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```